# What is the history of the variable names x and xs?

Tags: haskell, naming-conventions

I'm trying to pick up a bit of Haskell, and I'm alternating between awe and befuddlement. One of the really alienating things for me, trivial as this may seem, is the pattern matching idiom `(x:xs)`. Where do those variable names come from? They could be anything -- `(kernel:cob)`, `(spam:eggs)` (tipping my hand a bit), or -- most sensibly, to my mind, `(h:t)`, standing for 'head' and 'tail'.

I suppose the `x` prefix is useful for indicating that both items come from the same list, so then `(xh:xt)` or even just `(x:xt)` if you're feeling especially terse. But why *s*? What does it mean? Where did it come from? I feel, at the moment, that knowing would help me cope with my confusion.

Perhaps I am thinking about this in the wrong way; please feel free to tell me so.

Comment: One reason is, that it is shorter than all of the other variants you suggest (except `h:t`, but you can only name one list like this). Another idiom you might feel strange of is that a worker loop is often called `go`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`x` is a common variable name in mathematics. `xs` is the plural form of `x` (get it?). In list pattern matching, `x` is one element, and `xs` is (generally) several.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I get `x`. But to me, pluralizing x suggests many of the same value as x. So if `x == 5`, then by that logic, `xs == [5,5,5,5,5]`. Perhaps it's just something I have to get used to.

Comment: well, they are the same _type_ of data as `x`...

Comment: If you have a list of say eggs then `egg:eggs` doesn't seem so weird, does it?  And if it's a list of anything (polymorphic), well then `x` isn't a worse name than anything else.  The convention of pluralizing `x` as `xs` was introduced by Phil Wadler, if memory serves me.

Comment: @jsau If you're pattern matching on a list of type `[a]`, you could also try writing your pattern as `(a:as)` and pronounce it "an a followed by more a's", maybe that seems more natural? You have to make sure you don't mix type and normal variables! This of course fails when you have multiple arguments involving typevar `a`, and that's where `x` and `xs` come in handy.

Comment: Thinking about it in terms of type is very helpful, thanks! @augustss, the `egg:eggs` example makes perfect sense. But is that idiomatic? Is it odd to do `item:items` for a polymorphic list?

Comment: @jsau I think `egg:eggs` is fairly idiomatic if you have a list of eggs.  I've certainly used it.  And there's nothing odd about `item:items`, but to me it is no more descriptive than `x:xs`.  In Haskell code you'll often find that identifiers that have a small scope have short names, whereas those with a bigger scope have longer name.

Comment: It's pretty common, in informal mathematical speech, to talk of (x₁,x₂,x₃,...) as a sequence of "exes".

Comment: It was Phil: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/19mw7v/on_f_readability/c8q2y8r

Answer (score 32):

We can take the origins of `x` back much further, of course :-) François Viète (1540-1603) produced a book titled *In artem
 analyticem isagoge* (“Introduction to
 the Analytic Art”), which was the first work that systematically used letters to represent numbers.

*Edit:* Porges, below, points me to the really cool *A History of Mathematical Notations* by Cajori. To my pleasant surprise, the entire work is available online: http://archive.org/details/historyofmathema031756mbp

Comment: This answer is awesome.

Comment: Lol, this goes back bit further than I had expected, but I like it.

Comment: I'm going to take issue with this answer :D A cursory examination of Cajori's *A History of Mathematical Notations* shows that *x* itself wasn't used by Viète, but was instead popularised by Descartes. Viète in general used *capital vowels* (A, I, O, V, Y) to represent unknowns. On Descartes: "The use of *z*, *y*, *x*, ... to represent unknowns is due to René Descartes, in his *La géométrie* (1637). Without comment, he introduces the use of the first letters of the alphabet to signify *known* quantities and the use of the last letters to signify *unknown* quantities."

Answer (score 8):

`x` is the european transcription of the arabic word شيء (pronounce 'chi', or 'chaï'. or 'tchi', depending on the accent). This word  means 'thing', or 'something' and was used by first arab and iranian mathematicians as a symbol to designate an unknown or unfixed value in a mathematical expression.

Back to these times, 'x' might have been considered by translators and european mathematicians as the closest approximation to this symbol of the unknown.

Comment: that's a nice folk etymology but there's really no evidence for it.

Comment: I cannot find the original version of Omar Khayyam's 'Treatise on Demonstrations of Problems of Algebra (1070)' .... but it's in it with some 3rd degree equations.

Comment: Where he is talking about "things":
By the help of God and with His precious assistance, I say that Algebra is a scientific art. The objects with which it deals are absolute numbers and measurable quantities which, though themselves unknown, are related to "things" which are known, whereby the determination of the unknown quantities is possible.

Comment: Right, but he talked about 'things' as such -- there's no evidence I know of that the "sound" of the _word_ thing turned into an 'x' in the process of translation.

Comment: As every and only french person knows, scientist from the middle east invented everything, from alpha to omega.

Comment: I did not know there were trolls on this site.... And, bad luck, alpha and omega do not come from the middle east, but from Greece..