# Where does the name "xs" for pattern matching come from?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the history of the variable names x and xs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267735/what-is-the-history-of-the-variable-names-x-and-xs)

Where does the canonical name "xs" in pattern matching come from?

e.g. in

```
reverse' []     = []
reverse' [x]    = [x]
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Is it supposed to be the plural of "x" ?

Comment: Perhaps 'conventional' rather than 'canonical'. It's a plural, yes.

Comment: Yes, it's the plural.  Introduced by Phil Wadler, I think.

Comment: You will also often see (h:t), or occasionally the longer form (head:tail), although that way is more common, I think, in Erlang.

Comment: On occasion, when pattern-matching nested lists I've used `((x:xs):xss)`, and for lists of tuples `((x, y):xys)`. Those might be an abuse of the idiom though. :]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's the way I've always read it, you have the singular and the plural, So `x:xs` or `y:ys` etc.

It doesn't actually have any meaning by itself, it's just a convention.

IIRC it's also mentioned in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

---

**Edited**

My mistake - it's actually in [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/types-and-functions.html) in the chapter on types and functions.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know where exactly in "Learn you a Haskell" this is mentioned?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, I'm not sure if it's mentioned anywhere explicitly, but it's just considered the convention as Abizern said. (x:xs) just means a single x is attached as the head of a list of xs (essentially, sort of conveying the message that it is a list containing similar x elements). Not sure if this is a good enough explanation.

Comment: What nomenclature should I use for objects?