# Representing a tail in Haskell

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the name “xs” for pattern matching come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701099/where-does-the-name-xs-for-pattern-matching-come-from)

I'm learning Haskell. Here is a function that calculates the sum

```
sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a  
sum' [] = 0  
sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs
```

I can't figure out that `xs` means. x - is the head, xs - is the tail. But is it written is xs and not as just x or s?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701099/where-does-the-name-xs-for-pattern-matching-come-from

Comment: I'm not asking about why is called xs (and not ca or xw or bq). I'm asking about what does it mean exactly or how does it work? I guess there should be only one character.

Comment: It's just a variable name. It can be anything that's allowed by the naming rules. You can read about the syntax of pattern matching in general for example here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x` and `xs` are just variable names; you could use `fred` and `wilma` instead, for example. But it's very common to call the head of a list `x`, and the tail `xs` (pronounced exes), because it gives you a hint that `x` is a single element, while `xs` may contain multiple elements.

The example you've given uses pattern matching, which is a nifty feature. The line

```
 sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs
```

basically says "take the input parameter to sum', and split it after the first element. Call the first element `x` and the rest of the list `xs`". It would be essentially equivalent to:

```
 sum' list = x + sum' xs
     where x = head list
           xs = tail list
```

Comment: I was confused because I thought that xs were 2 variables for some reason.

Comment: `xs` is a single variable, but it is a list of elements whereas `x` is just one element. To give you a concrete example, if `(x:xs)` is `"hello"`, then `x` is `'h'` and `xs` is `"ello"`.