# Why do Clojure devs use "xs" for function args?

Tags: parameters, clojure, naming-conventions

In most languages there are conventions around arguments. Such as in nested loops you might use `i` at the top level, then `j`, then `k`.

But in Clojure I don't know what the convention is. I've seen, more often than not, the use of `xs` in function arguments; so why is that? Does it mean something specific? Are there other conventions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the naming convention, you can refer to [Clojure library coding standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards)

Specifically:

```
Follow clojure.core's example for idiomatic names like pred and coll.

in fns
    f, g, h - function input
    n - integer input usually a size
    index - integer index
    x, y - numbers
    s - string input
    coll - a collection
    pred - a predicate closure
    & more - variadic input
in macros
    expr - an expression
    body - a macro body
    binding - a macro binding vector
```

Comment: Interesting. Also no mention of xs which I see a lot of. Unless that's a combination of x and s as per your linked example. But then that would suggest a numerical string? Where as another poster has suggested xs means "a number of items" (like fn args)

Comment: I look 'xs' as the plural form of 'x'.

Answer (score 11):

I.m not sure it's a standard but very often the convention is `x` for a simple variable and `xs` for a variable that represents a sequence. The 's' stands for sequence or a plural, which is convenient.

For instance in destructuring you can use `[x & xs]` for the first and the following. 
You will find also `idx` for index and `idxs` for *more indexes*.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell and F# follow the same naming standard/pattern.  The `xs` is the plural formed of `x`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6267767/2370606

Comment: Agreed - Clojure itself does not use `xs` much, but the idiom definitely comes in from ML (ancestor to both Haskell and F#)